# AZURE APIM Redirect URL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have an API management instance (https://my-apim.azure-api.net) with several APIs. I need to implement a GET where APIM redirects to the login page (eg https://www.mywebsite.com/login ) if my APIM is called without the API suffix (eg "/login").

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your **APIM Instance** in the Azure Portal > Select **Identities**
  under Developer Portal (left index) and Click on Add.
- In the **Add Identity Provider** > Select Azure Active Directory or AAD B2C if your site is B2C tenant.
- Copy the new URL (i.e.,) sign-in URL from the Redirect URL Box

[image]

The same copied ***redirect URL*** should be added in ***App Registrations*** with your   APIM Instance.

[image]

Please refer this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad) regarding how to configure your APIM Instance to redirect to sign-in URL and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c) is for if your site registered under Azure AD B2C.